# Creating file in Google Drive with a Blob results in empty file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am writing an Apps Script that fetches a file via the UrlFetchApp and writes it to Google Drive.

Snippet:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log("Response code: " + response.getResponseCode());
var blob = response.getBlob();
mimeType = response.getHeaders()['Content-type'];
Logger.log("MIMEType: " + mimeType);
Logger.log("Response size (Content-Length): " + response.getHeaders()['Content-Length']);
Logger.log("Blob size: " + blob.getBytes().length);
newFile = {
  'mimeType' : mimeType,
  'title' : 'test.txt',
  'parents' : [{
    'kind' : 'drive#parentReference',
    'id' : driveFolderId
  }]
};
file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, blob);
Logger.log("Drive file size: " + file.fileSize);
```

Running the above results in the following log messages:

```
[14-09-07 17:29:01:619 PDT] Response code: 200
[14-09-07 17:29:01:620 PDT] MIMEType: application/octet-stream
[14-09-07 17:29:01:620 PDT] Response size (Content-Length): 5
[14-09-07 17:29:01:621 PDT] Blob size: 5
[14-09-07 17:29:02:537 PDT] Drive file size: 0
```

Navigating to Drive confirms that the file exists, is in the right folder, but has a size of 0.

It seems the blob is not making it into the file via the insert() method. I have tried using insert() with no data and then update() with the blob, with the same outcome.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the Drive API, but I know you can also use the DriveApp service.  (Which is different)  [Create File Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(String,String,String))  This is the documentation for insert: [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)  I don't see an option for isRoot.

Comment: Removed isRoot. Using `DriveApp.createFile(blob)` results in an error on that line: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Comment: I tested your code on another url and had no issue... the drive file has the same length as the blob. Do you know what data should be shown with these 5 bytes ? Is this data  a valid text content for the file ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use Drive.Files.insert(...) (experimental feature) instead of DriveApp.createFile(blob). (And did you activate the project in the google developper console?)